# Permutation of a list toward a symbol

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Here is a question difficult to explain (it's the reason of the weird title).

Say I have a set of elements

```
s = {a, b, c}
```

for wich I want to construct the set of all possible permutations of the form

```
s = {a ** b, a ** c, b ** c}
```

where `**` stands for either `>`, or `<`. The desired output in this case is

> {{a < b, a < c, b < c},{a < b, a > c, b < c},{a < b, a < c, b > c},{a < b, a > c, b > c}, {a > b, a < c, b < c},{a > b, a > c, b < c},{a > b, a < c, b > c},{a < b, a > c, b > c}}

Comment: Thanks corey979  but it is not exactly what I expect. I want b ** a transformed eventually in a ** b and ** should be Greater ... or ->

Comment: corey979 I dont understand what is unclear here is on a simpler set what I expect {a, b, c}
Gives
{{a < b, a < c, b < c}, {a < b, c < a, b < c},{a < b, a < c, c < b}, {a < b, c < a, b < c},
{b < a, a < c, b < c}, {b < a, c < a, b < c},{b < a, a < c, c < b}, {b < a, c < a, b < c}}
or
{{a -> b, a -> c, b -> c}, {a -> b, c -> a, b -> c},{a -> b, a -> c, c -> b}, {a -> b, c -> a, b -> c},
{b -> a, a -> c, b -> c}, {b -> a, c -> a, b -> c},{b -> a, a -> c, c -> b}, {b -> a, c -> a, b -> c}}

Comment: Dear Cyrille, I took the liberty to rephrase your question. See if it's really what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
s = {a, b, c}
```

make

```
sub = Subsets[s, {2}]
```

> {{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}}

and

```
tup = Tuples[{Greater, Less}, {Length@sub}]
```

> {{Greater, Greater, Greater}, {Greater, Greater, Less}, {Greater, 
>     Less, Greater}, {Greater, Less, Less}, {Less, Greater, 
>     Greater}, {Less, Greater, Less}, {Less, Less, Greater}, {Less, Less,
>      Less}}

Then

```
Table[MapThread[Apply, {tup[[i]], sub}], {i, 1, Length@tup}]
```

> {{a > b, a > c, b > c}, {a > b, a > c, b < c}, {a > b, a < c, 
>     b > c}, {a > b, a < c, b < c}, {a < b, a > c, b > c}, {a < b, a > c,
>      b < c}, {a < b, a < c, b > c}, {a < b, a < c, b < c}}

Comment: Ok I was wrong but I want all the possible permutations.  Not only {a > b, a > c, a > d, b > c, b > d, c > d} but also {b > a, a > c, a > d, b > c, b > d, c > d} , {b > a, c > a, a > d, b > c, b > d, c > d}... And how to replace > by -> ?

Comment: I have edited the question but I was precise I have writen   a symbol like (<) or an arrow of substitution (->)